# Delete records from tables of (2x many-to-many relationship)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a database with 5 tables

```
[Person]
-PersonId PK
-First name
-Middle name
-Surname
-Type

[Resident]
-PersonId  PK FK
-AddressId PK FK


[Addresse]
-AddressId PK
-Road
-Number
-Postal code
-City
-Type

[TelephoneOwner]
-TelephoneId PK FK
-PersonId PK FK

[Telephone]
-TelephoneId PK
-TelephoneNumber 
-Type
```

All my FK constraint are using

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The relationship is that a person can have multiple addresses and an address can have multiple persons.
A person can have multiple Telephones and a Telephone can have multiple persons.

I would like to delete everything connected to a person using his first name. Of course addresses/Telephones used by other people should remain in the database.

Comment: `delete everything connected to a person using his first name` There might be more than one person with the same first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With foreign keys, CASCADE effects the CHILD table when you update/delete the PARENT table.

You delete from Person: that is a parent table of Resident and TelephoneOwner.  Any records for the person you delete will be removed from those two tables.  It will not cascade from Resident and TelephoneOwner to Telephone or Addresse. If you want to keep those talbe clean, you could potentially schedule a job to clean out these tables periodically, or add a trigger on Person to check if it leaves a phone number or address with no owning person. In that case delete the phone number or address.

Per request, an example trigger is included below.  Be aware that triggers can cause performance issues if your system is constantly deleting and updating.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[some_trigger_name]
        ON [dbo].[Person]
      FOR DELETE
    AS
    BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE 
    FROM Addresse
    WHERE AddressId IN(-- Select the Addresses associated with people who were just deleted.
    SELECT R1.AddressId FROM DELETED JOIN Resident R1 on DELETED.PersonId  = R1.PersonId 
    EXCEPT
    -- Substract Addresses that have a Person associated with them other then a Person who was just deleted.
    SELECT R2.AddressId FROM Resident R2 
    WHERE R2.PersonId  NOT IN(SELECT PersonId  from DELETED))
    END
    GO
```

You can modify this for updates and to delete telephones as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am not familiar with triggers and after having spend time looking on the net for at way to add triggers. Can you maybe write a suggestion.

Comment: @MortenGodrimJensen Take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx  Because you tagged the question as tsql, I assume you are running SQL Server.  I will update my answer with a trigger you can use as a starting point.